# jQuery validation is not working : Need to know the error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have implemented some validations to a simple login page and applied some jQuery validations on button click but the code isn't working. I tried checking console but it was not giving me any errors. Please see the code for your reference:
 Could you guys tell me the error?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){       
                $("#form").validate({
                    alert("hi");
                    rules: {
                        name: {
                            required: true,
                            midlength: 5,

                        },
                        email: {
                            required: true,
                            email: true,
                        },
                        password: {
                            required: true,
                            midlength: 5,
                            equalTo: "#verify",

                        },
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>

        <style>
            label{
                width: 150px;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            label.error{
                color: red,
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <form id="form">

        <label>Name : </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" /><br/>

        <label>Email : </label>
        <input type="text" name="email"/ ><br/>

        <label>Password : </label>
        <input type="text" name="pass" /><br/>

        <label>Verify Password : </label>
        <input type="text" name="verify" id="verify" /><br/>

        <input type="submit" />

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look right:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate"></script>
```

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure the file exists with that filename in the js folder. Check the browser console to see if you get any errors - currently I'd expect your code to say "jquery.validate not found".

Comment: Very clear and well explained. Thank you! thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

there is a comma at end of

```
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    midlength: 5,
                    equalTo: "#verify",

                },
```

that break js execution